# React Native Modal and UI Kitten Modal Component with Expo

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I am creating an IOS App using Expo that has a Bottom Tab Navigator. Each screen of the navigator contains a Stack Navigator within it. Some of the items on the screen of the Stack Navigator have buttons that trigger UI Kitten Component Modals. However, after the Modal is dismissed from the screen I am fed this error.

```
measure cannot find view with tag #(null)
```

I've tried to use instead the React Native library's Modal component yet the same error persists. Thus, I'm assuming UI Kitten's Component Modal is built upon React Native's Modal.

This error quickly eats away at the performance of my app. Screens begin to take seconds to open after a user first encounters an error. Is there a solution to this?

My modal code looks along the lines of:

```ts
import { useContext } from "react";
import { VisibilityContext } from "../context/visibility";
import { Modal } from "@ui-kitten/components";
import { ItemModal } from "./ItemModal";

export const Modals = () => {
    const { visible, toggleVisibility } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

   return (
       <Modal
            animationType="fade"
            visible={visible}
            backdropStyle={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" }}
            onBackdropPress={toggleVisibility}
        >
            <ItemModal />
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!